# What does "get by someone" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I've come across it in the first episode of the fifth season of *the Walking Dead*. The cotext is Rick and his friends try to get to his other friends locked in a car train in place overrun by zombies.

> Rick: If we run, we can **get by** them. They are distrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get by a person or persons is to succeed in passing them, especially if they will try to stop you.